# Not able to escape Quote in Validation Rule message on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have following VF page -

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
  <apex:form>
  <apex:messages/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Quote Escape Test" mode="edit">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Fields" columns="1">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.name}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.stagename}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.closedate}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

when validation rule fired it looks as below  (Error: Validation Rule with "Quotes" and Broken.)

[image: when validation rule fired it looks as below]

Validation rule is defined as follows -

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could switch to using [apex:pageMessages](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm) as it has an escape attribute that will stop the `"` being converted to `&quot;`. You need to be aware of the potential JavaScript security issues in doing this.

```
<apex:pageMessages escape="false">
```

As Peter commented, this includes a lot more markup and formatting than apex:Messages.

---

Another, less desirable, alternative would be using JavaScript to correct the encoding of the double quote.

Comment: The apex:pageMessages will work for the top of the page message, although the output format is very different than the data list format of the apex:messages.  Still, there doesn't seem to be a clean (i.e. no JavaScript) solution for the message when the Error Location is field.

Comment: @Daniel Ballinger - that works for top message, but I think as Peter Said there is no clean solution for field level message.

Comment: @PeterKnolle Quite right, I've updated the answer to make the formatting differences clearer.

Comment: @PrafullaPatil Agreed, it won't help for the field level message. I'm not sure what else you could do. Maybe try hacking the validation rule via the meta data to remove the encoding on the quotes? Although the more secure approach would be for Salesforce to encode the characters on the way out of the database.

Answer (score 3):

Use a single quote instead of a double quote as in `Validation Rule with 'Quotes' and Broken`.